# Trying to connect Android Studio to a MySQL Database via PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I have a simple form, which when filled out should insert data into a database (localhost) using php.
When I click on the button, it says Application name has unfortunately stopped working.

Here is my code

Main Java Class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://localhost/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */


    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {



                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }



}
```

JSONParser Class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Main Activity(Containing the form)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input Name -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<!-- Price Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Age"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input Price -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<!-- Description Label -->
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"/>

<!-- Input description -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:lines="4"
    android:gravity="top"/>

<!-- Button Create Product -->
<Button android:id="@+id/btnCreateProduct"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cambiopune.onlinedatabase" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <activity android:name=".JSONParser" />
    </activity>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

The log error that I get on button click

```
 03-31 11:04:19.290  20660-20696/cambiopune.onlinedatabase E/Buffer Error﹕             Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

   03-31 11:04:19.290  20660-20696/cambiopune.onlinedatabase E/JSON Parser﹕   Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

  03-31 11:04:19.297  20660-20696/cambiopune.onlinedatabase E/AndroidRuntime﹕`    enter code here` FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
 Process: cambiopune.onlinedatabase, PID: 20660
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing             doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
        at                cambiopune.onlinedatabase.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:106)
        at cambiopune.onlinedatabase.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:79)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
           at          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
           at          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: So, you actually have a MySQL database and PHP server running on your phone? "localhost" for the app would, in theory, be the device itself. Just trying to verify the context of your question...

Comment: I have a MySQL database on phpMyAdmin via my computer. As in I access the database via a browser on my computer, whilst I run the application on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here ,

```
json = sb.toString();
```

Make sure your sb object is not null.

Comment: How do I ensure that its not null?

Comment: check weather you get a valid response from the service

Answer (score 0):

So you should probably note that "localhost" is a name for the device where the script or web server is running. If you say "localhost" on your Android device, it will probably try to find a server running on your Android device.

If you are running a web server on your computer, then your network will assign an IP address to that machine. Look at your network settings, and then tell your Android application what the address is... instead of "localhost"

Also, if you are using DHCP on your network, your computer (and maybe your phone) will get re-assigned. If you computer gets a new IP address, nothing will work.

Also, if you your phone is using WiFi on the same the same network, you are fine. If you switch to 4G or another WiFi network, it probably won't work. There is no routing table to handle the requests.